# Google Cloud Stackdriver: Metric grouped by ip

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I want to create stackdriver metrics, based on the ip and the frequency of requests an ip makes.

Therefore I would like to group by ip (the IP address of a requesting client) my loadbalancer logs, and if the number of requests exceed a threshold sent a notification.

Edit:

A workaround to achieve this.

1. Go to Stackdriver Logging and create a User-defined Metric that counts the total requests.
2. Fire an alarm when requests exceed a threshold.
3. Alarms call a lambda function that create a sync from stackdriver to bigquery
4. Execute the queries in order to find out the ip that causes the trouble

Comment: In your question, does "ip" mean the IP address of a requesting client or the IP of a GCP resource or something else?

Comment: The IP address of a requesting client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box solution so there can be a workaround with BigQuery

1. Go to Stackdriver Logging and create a User-defined Metric that counts the total requests.
2. Fire an alarm when requests exceed a threshold.
3. Alarms call a lambda function that create a sync from stackdriver to bigquery
4. Execute the queries in order to find out the ip that causes the trouble

Answer (score 1):

- In Stackdriver Logging, create a User-defined Metric (myMetric) [1] filtered on the desired IP address,
- In Stackdriver Monitoring, find resource type and metric by locating myMetric to create the chart.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/

Comment: Yes this is what I did to make it working. However since I wanted to get statistics per ip I created a sink towards the big query and created a query which would display the ip with the most requests.